# Problemas com a biblioteca <string.h>

Tags: c, funções

Boa noite pessoal!

Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho de faculdade utilizando funções, structs e arquivos, e estou tendo problemas exatamente com a biblioteca `<string.h>`.

Basicamente, o usuário se cadastra e os dados dele são mandados para um arquivo `BancodeUsuarios.txt`, isso na função `Cadastrar`, já na função `Login` era para ele rodar o arquivo e verificar usando o `strcmp` se o `usuário` e `senha` são iguais a 0, porem na hora de rodar ele grita que existe algum erro no uso da `strcmp` e na biblioteca, mais especificamente o erro:

```
[Warning] passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[Note] expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

Esse segundo em especial abre essa página:
[O arquivo aberto quando clico no erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIlma.png)

Podem me ajudar? Eu não faço ideia de qual o meu erro com essa biblioteca. Vou colocar abaixo o código, também gostaria de saber se estou no caminho certo.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    //Cadastro de novo usuário
    void Cadastro(char Nome[100], char User[15], char Email[50], char Sexo[10], int Idade, int CPF, int Senha){
    
        FILE *buser;
        buser = fopen("BancodeUsuarios.txt","w");
    
        printf("----------Cadastro----------\n");
    
        printf("Nome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(Nome);
    
    
        printf("Email: ");
        gets(Email);
    
    
        printf("Idade: ");
        scanf("%i", &Idade);
    
        printf("Sexo: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(Sexo);
    
       printf("CPF: ");
       scanf("%i", &CPF);
    
       printf("Nome de usuario: ");
       fflush(stdin);
       gets(User);
    
       printf("Senha: ");
       scanf("%i", &Senha);
    
    
    //Colocando o conteudo no BancodeUsuarios.txt
       fprintf(buser,"-----------------------------------");
       fprintf(buser,"Nome: %s\n", Nome);
       fprintf(buser,"Email: %s\n", Email);
       fprintf(buser,"Idade: %i anos\n",Idade);
       fprintf(buser,"Sexo: %s\n", Sexo);
       fprintf(buser,"CPF: %i\n\n", CPF);
       fprintf(buser,"Nome de usuario: %s\n", User);
       fprintf(buser,"Senha: %i\n\n", Senha);
     }

     //Login
     void Login(char UserVrfc[15], int SenhaVrfc){
    
        //Par opção de Cadastro
        char Nm[100], Us[15], Mail[50], Sx[10];
        int Idad, Sen, C_P_F;
    
    
        //Variaveis auxiliares
        char r[1000];
        int aux1, aux2;
        int resp, sesim;
    
        printf("------------Login------------\n");
        printf("Usuario: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(UserVrfc);
    
    
        printf("Senha: ");
        scanf("%i", &SenhaVrfc);
    
        FILE *buser;
        buser = fopen("BancodeUsuarios.txt","r");
    
        //Verifica o nome de usuário
    
        aux1 = 0;
    
        while(fscanf(buser,"%s",r) !=EOF){
           sesim = strcmp(r,UserVrfc);
           if(sesim == 0){
                aux1 = 1;
                break;
           }
        }
    
        fclose(buser);
    
        //Verifica a senha
    
        buser = fopen("BancodeUsuarios.txt","r");
    
        aux2 = 0;
    
        while(fscanf(buser,"%s",r) !=EOF){
           sesim = strcmp(r,SenhaVrfc);
           if(sesim == 0){
                aux2 = 1;
                break;
           }
        }
    
        //Verificação para login
     
        fclose(buser);
    
        if(aux1 == 1 && aux2 == 1){
            printf("Bem-vindo!\n");
        }else if(aux1 == 1 && aux2 == 0){
            printf("Senha incorreta\n");
        }else{
            printf("Usuário inexistente, digite 1 para se cadastrar ou 2 para sair\n");
            if(resp == 1){
                system ("cls");
                Cadastro(Nm, Us, Mail, Sx, Idad, C_P_F, Sen);
            }
        }
    }


    int main(){
    
        //variaveis de cadastro
        char Nm[100], Us[15], Mail[50], Sx[10];
        int Idad, Sen, C_P_F;
    
        //variaveis de login
        char Usie[15], Snh;
    
        //variaveis auxiliares
        int resp;
    
        //Criando banco de usuários
    
        printf("----------PetOnline------------\n");
        printf("Bem-vindo ao seu Petshop Online!\n");
        printf("Somos uma petshop de bem com mundo, que propoe vender produtos\n");
        printf("que sejam adequados para seu animalzinho e ainda ajudar o mundo\n");
        printf("e aqueles que precisam, com suas doacoes montamos campanhas de\n");
        printf("castracao e ajudamos animais em situacao de rua ou que necessitem");
        printf("de ajuda! Entao muito obrigada!\n");
        printf("Se for novo aqui, digite 1 para se cadastrar e fazer parte desse\n");
        printf("projeto do bem!\n");
        printf("Agora se ja fizer parte da nossa familia digite 2 para fazer seu\n");
        printf("cadastro!\n");
    
        scanf("%i", &resp);
    
        switch(resp){
           case 1:
                system ("cls");
                Cadastro(Nm, Us, Mail, Sx, Idad, C_P_F, Sen);
                break;
           case 2:
                system ("cls");
                Login(Usie, Snh);
                break;
         }
    
         return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: `SenhaVrfc` é um `int`, não tem sentido utilizar a função `strcmp` para comparar com a string `r`.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá amigo. Estou na faculdade também e entendo sua euforia, mas uma dica de quem já apanhou na vida: seja específico. Culpar a biblioteca <string.h> pelo erro em seu código pode lhe custar um lugar ao sol aqui nesta grande comunidade. Voltando a sua questao, vou citar alguns pontos:

1. Esqueca imediatamente o comando gets(). Ele está descontinuado no c e já foi substituido por fgets(). Uma alternativa mais simples ao fgets é voce usar um scanf() com um getchar() depois, para que o enter (a famosa quebra de linha) nao atrapalhe seu codigo. Exemplo:

   ```
    char textoDigitado[100];
    printf("Digite seu texto de até 100 caracteres: "):
    scanf("%s",&textoDigitado);
    getchar(); /* colocando esta funcao no final, o proximo scanf que voce usar
    nao pegará o enter. */
   ```
2. Tentei entender o porquê de voce limpar o buffer em vários momentos do codigo com o comando "fflush(stdin)", mas percebi que nao tem sentido mesmo. Por favor remova todos do seu codigo imediatamente.
3. Seu comando de leitura e comparacao do usuario e senha está um tanto quanto fragil. O erro citado por voce no enunciado do topico aconteceu por causa do comando abaixo:

   ```
   while(fscanf(buser,"%s",r) !=EOF){
      sesim = strcmp(r,SenhaVrfc);
   if(sesim == 0){
        aux2 = 1;
        break;
     }
    }
   ```

r é um ponteiro do tipo char e Senhavrfc é um integer, ou seja nao é possivel comparar um caractere com um inteiro. otimizando os dois whiles de comparacao de usuario e senha, seu codigo ficaria assim:

```
   // VERIFICANDO O USUARIO NO BANCO DE DADOS.
   char usuarioBanco[100];
      while(fscanf(buser,"%s",usuarioBanco) !=EOF) {
        if (strcmp(usuarioBanco,UserVrfc) == 0) {
            aux1 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

 // VERIFICANDO A SENHA NO BANCO DE DADOS.TXT
  int senhaBanco;
     while(fscanf(buser,"%s %d",r,&senhaBanco) !=EOF) {
        if ((strcmp(r,"Senha:") == 0) && (senhaBanco == SenhaVrfc)) {
            aux2 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

4. Seu codigo, com as modificacoes que propus, ficará assim:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>


   //Cadastro de novo usuário
   void Cadastro(char Nome[100], char User[15], char Email[50], char Sexo[10], int Idade, int CPF, int Senha) {

    FILE *buser;
    buser = fopen("BancodeUsuarios.txt","w");

    printf("----------Cadastro----------\n");

    printf("Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", Nome);
    getchar();

    printf("Email: ");
    scanf("%s", Email);
    getchar();

    printf("Idade: ");
    scanf("%i", &Idade);
    getchar();
    printf("Sexo: ");
    scanf("%s", Sexo);
    getchar();

    printf("CPF: ");
    scanf("%i", &CPF);
    getchar();

    printf("Nome de usuario: ");
    scanf("%s", User);
    getchar();

    printf("Senha: ");
    scanf("%i", &Senha);
    getchar();

   //Colocando o conteudo no BancodeUsuarios.txt
    fprintf(buser,"-----------------------------------");
    fprintf(buser,"Nome: %s\n", Nome);
    fprintf(buser,"Email: %s\n", Email);
    fprintf(buser,"Idade: %i anos\n",Idade);
    fprintf(buser,"Sexo: %s\n", Sexo);
    fprintf(buser,"CPF: %i\n\n", CPF);
    fprintf(buser,"Nome de usuario: %s\n", User);
    fprintf(buser,"Senha: %i\n\n", Senha);
   }

   //Login
   void Login(char UserVrfc[15], int SenhaVrfc) {

    //Par opção de Cadastro
    char Nm[100], Us[15], Mail[50], Sx[10];
    int Idad, Sen, C_P_F;


    //Variaveis auxiliares
    char r[1000];
    int aux1, aux2;
    int resp;

    printf("------------Login------------\n");
    printf("Usuario: ");
    scanf("%s", UserVrfc);
    getchar();


    printf("Senha: ");
    scanf("%i", &SenhaVrfc);
    getchar();

    FILE *buser;
    buser = fopen("BancodeUsuarios.txt","r");

    //Verifica o nome de usuário

    aux1 = 0;
    char usuarioBanco[100];
    while(fscanf(buser,"%s",usuarioBanco) !=EOF) {
        if (strcmp(usuarioBanco,UserVrfc) == 0) {
            aux1 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(buser);

   //Verifica a senha

    buser = fopen("BancodeUsuarios.txt","r");

    aux2 = 0;
    int senhaBanco;
    while(fscanf(buser,"%s %d",r,&senhaBanco) !=EOF) {
        if ((strcmp(r,"Senha:") == 0) && (senhaBanco == SenhaVrfc)) {
            aux2 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

   //Verificação para login

    fclose(buser);

    if(aux1 == 1 && aux2 == 1) {
        printf("Bem-vindo!\n");
    } else if(aux1 == 1 && aux2 == 0) {
        printf("Senha incorreta\n");
    } else {
        printf("Usuário inexistente, digite 1 para se cadastrar ou 2 para sair\n");
        if(resp == 1) {
            system("cls");
            Cadastro(Nm, Us, Mail, Sx, Idad, C_P_F, Sen);
           }
       }
   }


   int main() {

    //variaveis de cadastro
    char Nm[100], Us[15], Mail[50], Sx[10];
    int Idad, Sen, C_P_F;

    //variaveis de login
    char Usie[15], Snh;

    //variaveis auxiliares
    int resp;

    //Criando banco de usuários

    printf("----------PetOnline------------\n");
    printf("Bem-vindo ao seu Petshop Online!\n");
    printf("Somos uma petshop de bem com mundo, que propoe vender produtos\n");
    printf("que sejam adequados para seu animalzinho e ainda ajudar o mundo\n");
    printf("e aqueles que precisam, com suas doacoes montamos campanhas de\n");
    printf("castracao e ajudamos animais em situacao de rua ou que necessitem");
    printf("de ajuda! Entao muito obrigada!\n");
    printf("Se for novo aqui, digite 1 para se cadastrar e fazer parte desse\n");
    printf("projeto do bem!\n");
    printf("Agora se ja fizer parte da nossa familia digite 2 para fazer seu\n");
    printf("login!\n");

    scanf("%i", &resp);

    switch(resp) {
    case 1:
        system ("cls");
        Cadastro(Nm, Us, Mail, Sx, Idad, C_P_F, Sen);
        break;
    case 2:
        system ("cls");
        Login(Usie, Snh);
        break;
    }

    return 0;

    }
   ```

Ainda existem opcoes de melhorias, como voce alocar dinamicamente a memoria das variaveis e criar um while para os menus de opcoes, mas focando no objetivo do seu topico, as informacoes acima resolverao seu problema. Abraco

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas, eu não imaginava que o gets() já estivesse em desuso, ou tampouco conhecia a função getchar(), ainda tenho muito a aprender!